# Foundation css div placement

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to position 3 divs using Foundation 5 framework. The first two (div 1, div 2) I want them to be full height of the browser window, and the 3rd one can be just a plain div.

How should I proceed? Code examples are highly appreciated.

[image: Positioning]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-2 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-9 columns"></div>
</div>
```

its a simple use of zurbs [grid layout](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html).

for full width adjust these settings int your `_settings.scss` file.

```
$row-width: rem-calc(1000); //make this max of screen size
$column-gutter: rem-calc(0);
$total-columns: 12 ;
```

you can also explicitly state `width:100%;` with a class or id.

Comment: That's about right. Any way of making row class full width? should I add a custom css and specify a width for .row?

Comment: It's almost right. I tried setting .row { width: 100%; } but it still doesn't go full width. Is there any work-around so I won't mess with the scss file using fixed values?

Comment: set the padding and margin to 0.

Comment: when setting .row { width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; } it only alings it to the left. Width doesn't change... And I don't use SCSS so I dont have that file...

Comment: Try adding max-width: none to .row